# Get the inputs from a ListView.Builder input fields? and pass as json

Tags: api, flutter, listview, dart

I have this view. in my flutter application inside a ModalBottomSheet view.

***Input Field builder***

```
              Expanded(
                    flex: 6,
                    child: ListView.builder(
                      itemCount: 5,
                      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                        return Container(
                          margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 4.0, horizontal: 4.0),
                          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.95,
                          // height: 100.0,
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(
                                10.0,
                              )),
                              color: Color(0xFF01816B),
                              shape: BoxShape.rectangle),
                          //
                          child: Column(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                            children: [
                              Padding(
                                padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                    horizontal: 4.0, vertical: 4.0),
                                child: Row(
                                  mainAxisAlignment:
                                      MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                                  children: [
                                    Expanded(
                                      flex: 1,
                                      child: Text(
                                        "Category",
                                        style: kSubContentStyleWhiteLight,
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                    Expanded(
                                      flex: 1,
                                      child: Text(
                                        "Food Type",
                                        style: kSubContentStyleWhiteLight,
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                    Expanded(
                                      flex: 1,
                                      child: Text(
                                        "Quantity",
                                        style: kSubContentStyleWhiteLight,
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ),
                              Padding(
                                padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                    horizontal: 4.0, vertical: 4.0),
                                child: Row(
                                  mainAxisAlignment:
                                      MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                                  children: [
                                    Expanded(
                                      flex: 1,
                                      child: Container(
                                        height: 48.0,
                                        padding: EdgeInsets.all(2.0),
                                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                            borderRadius:
                                                BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(
                                              10.0,
                                            )),
                                            color: Color(0xFF03B898),
                                            shape: BoxShape.rectangle),
                                        child: DropdownButton<String>(
                                          value: _categorySelected,
                                          // icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_downward),
                                          hint: Text(
                                            'Category',
                                            style: kMainContentStyleWhite,
                                          ),
                                          iconSize: 24,
                                          elevation: 16,
                                          style: kMainContentStyleLightBlack,
                                          onChanged: (String newValue) {
                                            setState(() {
                                              _categorySelected = newValue;
                                            });
                                          },
                                          items: _categoryList
                                              .map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>(
                                                  (String value) {
                                            return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                                              value: value,
                                              child: Text(value),
                                            );
                                          }).toList(),
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                    SizedBox(
                                      width: 8.0,
                                    ),
                                    Expanded(
                                      flex: 1,
                                      child: Container(
                                        height: 48.0,
                                        padding: EdgeInsets.all(2.0),
                                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                            borderRadius:
                                                BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(
                                              10.0,
                                            )),
                                            color: Color(0xFF03B898),
                                            shape: BoxShape.rectangle),
                                        child: DropdownButton<String>(
                                          value: _foodTypeSelected,
                                          hint: Text(
                                            'FoodType',
                                            style: kMainContentStyleWhite,
                                          ),
                                          iconSize: 24,
                                          elevation: 2,
                                          style: kMainContentStyleLightBlack,
                                          onChanged: (String newValue) {
                                            setState(() {
                                              _foodTypeSelected = newValue;
                                            });
                                          },
                                          items: _foodTypeList
                                              .map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>(
                                                  (String value) {
                                            return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                                              value: value,
                                              child: Text(value),
                                            );
                                          }).toList(),
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                    SizedBox(
                                      width: 8.0,
                                    ),
                                    Expanded(
                                      flex: 1,
                                      child: Container(
                                        height: 48.0,
                                        // color: Colors.grey[100],
                                        // padding: EdgeInsets.all(2.0),
                                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                            borderRadius:
                                                BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(
                                              10.0,
                                            )),
                                            color: Color(0xFF03B898),
                                            shape: BoxShape.rectangle),
                                        alignment: Alignment.center,
                                        child: TextFormField(
                                          // controller: _mealPlanQtyController,
                                          inputFormatters: [
                                            new LengthLimitingTextInputFormatter(
                                                3),
                                          ],
                                          // decoration: InputDecoration(
                                          //   border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                                          // ),
                                          keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                                          autofocus: false,
                                          validator: validateNumberDecimal,
                                          onSaved: (String value) {
                                            // _petWeight = value; //double.parse(value);
                                          },
//      initialValue: 'alucard@gmail.com',
                                          style: kMainContentStyleWhite,
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        );
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
```

Here I need to get every value for each item separately.(values are from two drop downs and a TextInputField).
Which I need to pass every input field(five input field list items are there) in the following format using an API

```
{
  "user_email": "email@m.com",
  "user_token": "thisistoken",
  "feeding_plan_detail": {
    "quantity": "float",
    "food_id": "id",
    "feeding_plan_id": "id"
  }
}
```

how can I do this in flutter?

Answer (score 1):

Create a model class to store the input values.

```
class UserInputs {
    String category, foodType;
    double quantity;
    
    UserInputs({this.category = '', this.foodType = '', this.quantity = 0.0});
}
```

Inside you ModalBottomSheet view or Input Field builder class, create a list of `UserInputs` with default values & store each input value in this model object.

```
final _allUserInputs = List<UserInputs>[5];
for (var i = 0; i < _allUserInputs.length; i++) {
    _allUserInputs = UserInputs(); // obj with default values
}
```

Save each value of the user input in the object as follows:

```
Expanded(
      flex: 6,
      child: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: 5,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          return Container(
            margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 4.0, horizontal: 4.0),
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.95,
            // height: 100.0,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(
                  10.0,
                )),
                color: Color(0xFF01816B),
                shape: BoxShape.rectangle),
            //
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              children: [
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                      horizontal: 4.0, vertical: 4.0),
                  child: Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: [
                      Expanded(
                        flex: 1,
                        child: Text(
                          "Category",
                          style: kSubContentStyleWhiteLight,
                        ),
                      ),
                      Expanded(
                        flex: 1,
                        child: Text(
                          "Food Type",
                          style: kSubContentStyleWhiteLight,
                        ),
                      ),
                      Expanded(
                        flex: 1,
                        child: Text(
                          "Quantity",
                          style: kSubContentStyleWhiteLight,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                      horizontal: 4.0, vertical: 4.0),
                  child: Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: [
                      Expanded(
                        flex: 1,
                        child: Container(
                          height: 48.0,
                          padding: EdgeInsets.all(2.0),
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(
                                10.0,
                              )),
                              color: Color(0xFF03B898),
                              shape: BoxShape.rectangle),
                          child: DropdownButton<String>(
                            value: _categorySelected,
                            // icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_downward),
                            hint: Text(
                              'Category',
                              style: kMainContentStyleWhite,
                            ),
                            iconSize: 24,
                            elevation: 16,
                            style: kMainContentStyleLightBlack,
                            onChanged: (String newValue) {
                              setState(() {
                                _allUserInputs[index].category = newValue; // New
                              });
                            },
                            items: _categoryList
                                .map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>((String value) {
                              return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                                value: value,
                                child: Text(value),
                              );
                            }).toList(),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        width: 8.0,
                      ),
                      Expanded(
                        flex: 1,
                        child: Container(
                          height: 48.0,
                          padding: EdgeInsets.all(2.0),
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(
                                10.0,
                              )),
                              color: Color(0xFF03B898),
                              shape: BoxShape.rectangle),
                          child: DropdownButton<String>(
                            value: _foodTypeSelected,
                            hint: Text(
                              'FoodType',
                              style: kMainContentStyleWhite,
                            ),
                            iconSize: 24,
                            elevation: 2,
                            style: kMainContentStyleLightBlack,
                            onChanged: (String newValue) {
                              setState(() {
                                _allUserInputs[index].foodType = newValue; // New
                              });
                            },
                            items: _foodTypeList
                                .map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>((String value) {
                              return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                                value: value,
                                child: Text(value),
                              );
                            }).toList(),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        width: 8.0,
                      ),
                      Expanded(
                        flex: 1,
                        child: Container(
                          height: 48.0,
                          // color: Colors.grey[100],
                          // padding: EdgeInsets.all(2.0),
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(
                                10.0,
                              )),
                              color: Color(0xFF03B898),
                              shape: BoxShape.rectangle),
                          alignment: Alignment.center,
                          child: TextFormField(
                            // controller: _mealPlanQtyController,
                            inputFormatters: [
                              new LengthLimitingTextInputFormatter(3),
                            ],
                            // decoration: InputDecoration(
                            //   border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                            // ),
                            keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                            autofocus: false,
                            validator: validateNumberDecimal,
                            onSaved: (String value) {
                              _allUserInputs[index].quantity = double.parse(value); // New
                              // _petWeight = value; //double.parse(value);
                            },
                            //      initialValue: 'alucard@gmail.com',
                            style: kMainContentStyleWhite,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    ),
```